# Disable the security warning "Do you want to open this file? - Unknown Publisher" for a specific filetype

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, pdf, chm

I always get the annoying warning below when opening PDF files. Can I avoid this (for *.pdf)?
I use [PDFlite](http://pdflite.com) as my default PDF reader.

[image]

Comment: I would try unchecking the box just before "Always ask before opening this file."

Comment: It only disables the warning for the opened file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the post [Open File Security Warning - Enable or Disable](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/182353-open-file-security-warning-enable-disable.html) there are several ways to accomplish what you need, one of which is by editing the registry. (warning: Be careful when doing this!)

In the Registry Editor (`regedit`) navigate to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations
```

[image]
[image]

In the right pane of Associations, double click on `LowRiskFileTypes`.

Add or remove file the extensions using the same format, and click on OK when finished.

Close `regedit`, and reboot your computer.

You can also do this via the Group Policy Editor, see [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/182353-open-file-security-warning-enable-disable.html).

Comment: The key `Association` doesn't exist under `Policies`, which is an empty key. I've also searched `LowRiskFileTypes` term throughout the entire registry and no results were found.

Comment: Ok, I've found your source on [sevenforums](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/182353-open-file-security-warning-enable-disable.html), included in answer.

Comment: So what do you do when `Association` doesn't exist?

Answer (score 6):

On windows 10, the registry hack doesn't work, and neither does the Group Policy Editor, because neither of them exist. But I found a solution [here](http://www.overclock.net/a/how-to-disable-the-open-file-security-warning-in-windows-8). It involves going into your internet explorer settings (even if you don't use internet explorer). Click on the "Security" tab, then "Custom Level", then scroll down to "Launching applications and unsafe files", and check "Enable". Internet explorer doesn't like this and will remind you about it (as it does 3 times in the picture), but that's ok, because nobody uses Internet Explorer anyway!

[image: Picture of internet explorer security option]

Comment: [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](http://superuser.com/q/1018145)

Answer (score 0):

On my seven, it didn't work, this did (elevated command prompt):

```
ICACLS "%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs" /Setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)Medium

ICACLS "%userprofile%\Favorites\Links" /Setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)Medium

ICACLS "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch" /Setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)Medium

ICACLS "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User pinned\Taskbar" /Setintegritylevel (OI)(CI)Medium
```

Answer (score 0):

After the latest Win10 home update 1903, I began to get an"Unknown Publisher" warning for nearly all pdf files already on the system.  I added this key, and the popup warnings stopped.

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Associations]

"LowRiskFileTypes"=".pdf;"